# nodejs readline interface with stdin/stdout directs output back to input making a infinite loop

Tags: node.js, io, stdout, stdin, readline

This is what I want to do

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    rl.write("new line\n");
});
```

Essentially, every time I get a line of input, I want to print a new line to stdout (this includes the new line at the end). And I don't want to do this with `console.log`. As long as the new line is there, I end up with an infinite loop - the stuff I write now comes in as the new line on stdin.

My current workaround looks like this:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

var working = false;
rl.on('line', (line) => {
    if (!working) {
        working = true;
        rl.write("new line\n");
        working = false;
    }
});
```

I guess I don't really know why stdout is also coming back into stdin. And I'm hoping there is a cleaner way to solve this problem

Comment: Its happening because adding a "\n"  invokes a new line function which calls itself back again and again .  The (line) Emitted whenever the input stream receives an end of line (\n, \r, or \r\n), usually received when the user hits enter, or return

Comment: But stdout and stdin are normally considered 2 different streams. This wouldn't happen in other languages